# How do I set the gravity (property style) for a Toast in Kotlin (getting error)?

Tags: android, kotlin, toast

When I write this code:

```
var toast = Toast.makeText(
    this,
    "Toast at top!",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
)
toast.gravity = Gravity.TOP
toast.show()
```

I get the error "**Val cannot be reassigned**" on the `toast.gravity` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an extension function, but I just did this:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
```

By the way, you can also do this (if you want more options):

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP or Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0)
```

I hope this saves someone some time. I wish it was implemented by Android.

Comment: The reason it's like this is `Toast.setGravity()` in Java has more than one parameter so it cannot be converted to a property in Kotlin. So only `getGravity()` is converted, and the resulting `Toast.gravity` property is a read-only `val` rather than a `var`. It cannot be cleanly fixed with an extension property because the name of the extension `var` would overload the implicit `val`. It also doesn't really make sense to default to not changing the offset, because if you are changing the gravity, you would almost certainly want the offset to go in a different direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That makes sense... I just have never use the offset, so I don't like setting it every time. :D

Answer (score 1):

Or a single line answer using Kotlin scoping functions:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).apply {setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0); show() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
val toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
toast.show()
```